# Windows 8.1 phone toast notification navigating to specific page with object as parameter

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I have a toast notification which when touched should navigate to a specific page in the app and also send an object as parameter to be used in the navigated page.

I am unable to find a suitable method. i have tried the activated event but it is something that is not solving my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending push notification, you toast xml should have launch parameters.

When the user taps or clicks the notification, the associated app is automatically launched, and so its OnLaunched method is invoked. If we want to determine whether the app is activated by a toast notification click, we can use the Arguments property of the LaunchActivatedEventArgs object that is passed to this method.

Please have a look on this blog: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-app-activated-by-a-toast-notification/

Comment: I appreciate this but my toast doesn't seem to have any such property as Launch. I believe this solution is not for windows 8.1 phone. Most importantly, a string is easy to pass but i have an object to pass as parameter. Please help

Comment: To pass an object as a parameter you can simply serialize it and once it's serialized it becomes a string you pass it on as a parameter and then once it's received, deserialize it and you'll have the object. Also, the blog link I provided is for Windows RunTime (RT). I've personally tried the solution before and it works perfectly fine. Are you using Windows 8.1 Silverlight?

Comment: Windows rt 8.1 , not silverlight. The serialising works for me thanks but how do i go about launching the specific page?

Comment: @Dev_Man you're setting the toast in xml, try putting in a launch parameter as shown in the link, if there is an issue then put a breakpoint on the on launched event and open the app via a toast notification and check for the arguments passed in and please attach em to your question. try launching the app from different toast notifications who's content and all parameters are different.

Comment: To do so, you have to run your app, then from application lifecycle option in visual studio select suspend and shut down and then launch from the toast notification this ways app would launch with debugger attached